# fixing drifting issue for elechouse voice recog module v3.1 and MPU6050 sensor for head mouse even after doing sensor calibration?

Tags: mpu6050, arduino-pro-micro

For my head mouse project which is based on the voice recognition module V3.1 for left click, double click, right click operations, MPU 6050 accelerometer and gyroscope for cursor movement, I am facing a problem. When I just use the MPU 6050 accelerometer and gyroscope sensor for cursor movement, the mouse cursor moves smoothly (calibration has been done). But when I integrate it with the voice recognition module, the cursor starts to drift. My code is given in this post too.

I have been using an arduino pro micro for this project. Please help. I have calibrated my MPU6050 , so it does not drift while working alone. But after integration with voice recog module (including calibration) , the drifting problem returns. I am powering the setup using a USB cable connected from the laptop to the arduino.

N.B: This is a project from a client. According to requirements, I need to make the head mouse wireless. I need suggestions for that too.

[image: Circuit connnection]

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "VoiceRecognitionV3.h"
#include <Mouse.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <I2Cdev.h>
#include <MPU6050.h>

VR myVR(8,9);    // 9:RX 8:TX

uint8_t records[7]; // save record
uint8_t buf[64];

MPU6050 mpu;
int16_t ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz, oax, oay, oaz, ogx, ogy, ogz;
int vx, vy;

#define leftRecord    (0)
#define rightRecord   (1) 
#define doubleRecord  (2)

/**
  @brief   Print signature, if the character is invisible, 
           print hexible value instead.
  @param   buf     --> command length
           len     --> number of parameters
*/
void printSignature(uint8_t *buf, int len)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<len; i++){
    if(buf[i]>0x19 && buf[i]<0x7F){
      Serial.write(buf[i]);
    }
    else{
      Serial.print("[");
      Serial.print(buf[i], HEX);
      Serial.print("]aurav");
    }
  }
}

/**
  @brief   Print signature, if the character is invisible, 
           print hexible value instead.
  @param   buf  -->  VR module return value when voice is recognized.
             buf[0]  -->  Group mode(FF: None Group, 0x8n: User, 0x0n:System
             buf[1]  -->  number of record which is recognized. 
             buf[2]  -->  Recognizer index(position) value of the recognized record.
             buf[3]  -->  Signature length
             buf[4]~buf[n] --> Signature
*/
void printVR(uint8_t *buf)
{
  Serial.println("VR Index\tGroup\tRecordNum\tSignature");
  Serial.print(buf[2], DEC);
  Serial.print("\t\t");

  if(buf[0] == 0xFF){
    Serial.print("NONE");
  }
  else if(buf[0]&0x80){
    Serial.print("UG ");
    Serial.print(buf[0]&(~0x80), DEC);
  }
  else{
    Serial.print("SG ");
    Serial.print(buf[0], DEC);
  }
  Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.print(buf[1], DEC);
  Serial.print("\t\t");
  if(buf[3]>0){
    printSignature(buf+4, buf[3]);
  }
  else{
    Serial.print("NONE");
  }
  Serial.println("\r\n");
}

void setup()
{
  /** initialize */
  Wire.begin();
  if (!mpu.testConnection()) {
    while (1);
    }

  myVR.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Elechouse Voice Recognition V3 Module\r\nControl LED sample");


  if(myVR.clear() == 0){
    Serial.println("Recognizer cleared.");
  }else{
    Serial.println("Not find VoiceRecognitionModule.");
    Serial.println("Please check connection and restart Arduino.");
    while(1);
  }

  if(myVR.load((uint8_t)leftRecord) >= 0){
    Serial.println("leftRecord loaded");
  }

  if(myVR.load((uint8_t)rightRecord) >= 0){
    Serial.println("rightRecord loaded");
  }

  if(myVR.load((uint8_t)doubleRecord) >= 0){
    Serial.println("doubleRecord loaded");
  }

}

void loop()
{
  int ret;
  ret = myVR.recognize(buf, 50);

  mpu.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);

  oax = ax-265;
  oay = ay+387;
  oaz = az+474; 
  ogx = gx-109;
  ogy = gy+35;
  ogz = gz+150;

  vx = gx/120;  
  vy = -gz/120; 

  Mouse.move(vx, vy);

  if(ret>0){

  switch(buf[1]){

    case leftRecord:
    Mouse.click(MOUSE_LEFT);
    delay(100);
    break;

    case rightRecord:
    Mouse.click(MOUSE_RIGHT);
    delay(100);
    break;

    case doubleRecord:
    Mouse.click(MOUSE_LEFT);
    Mouse.click(MOUSE_LEFT);
    delay(100);
    break;

    default:
    Serial.println("Record function undefined");
    break;
    }
    /** voice recognized */
    printVR(buf);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely the use of SoftwareSerial for your VR module communication. SoftwareSerial is notorious for breaking things. It disables interrupts, and hogs the CPU.

You should be using the hardware serial port instead which, on the Pro Mini, is completely separate to USB communication.